# Failed to convert output property 'CallFunc_ExecutePythonScript_result' Unreal

Tags: python, unreal-engine5

I'm busy making an editors utility eidget in Unreal but when i press the button to execute the code i get this error:

LogScript: Error: Script Msg: TypeError: /OpenAI/wChatGPT: Failed to convert output property 'CallFunc_ExecutePythonScript_result' (StrProperty) from attribute 'result' when calling function 'ExecuteUbergraph_wChatGPT' on 'Default__PythonScriptLibrary'
TypeError: NativizeProperty: Cannot nativize 'NoneType' as 'CallFunc_ExecutePythonScript_result' (StrProperty)
TypeError: Nativize: Cannot nativize 'NoneType' as 'String'
LogScript: Error: Script call stack:
/OpenAI/wChatGPT.wChatGPT_C.ExecuteUbergraph_wChatGPT <---
/OpenAI/wChatGPT.wChatGPT_C.BndEvt__wChatGPT_Submit_BTN_K2Node_ComponentBoundEvent_1_OnButtonClickedEvent__DelegateSignature

thanks so much

I've tried to google but i just can't find any results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.